# NiFi from hadoop to kafak with exactly once guarantee

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

Is it possible for NiFi to read from hdfs (or hive) and publish data-rows to kafka with exactly once delivery guarantee?

Answer (score 1):

Publishing to Kafka from NiFi is at-least-once guarantee because a failure could occur after Kafka has already received the message, but before NiFi receives the response, which could be due to a network issue, or maybe nifi crashed and restarted at that exact moment.

In any of those cases, the flow file would be put back in the original queue before the publish kafka processor (i.e. the session was never committed), and so it would be tried again.

Due to the threading model where different threads may execute the processor, it can't be guaranteed that the same thread that originally did the publishing will be the same thread that does the retry, and therefore can't make use of the "idempotent producer" concept.

Comment: Does this statement holds true as well when using PublishKafka setup with "use transactions" which (according to kafka doc) can allow producers to kafka to enable exactly-once-semantics?